# Can I prevent a secondary HDD from spinning up when waking my computer?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, sleep

I have a SSD as my booting hard drive. I also have a spinning HDD for large files and backups that does not need to run all the time. I have it on a timer, such that it spins down after being idle for 20 minutes. My issue is that it spins up each time I wake my computer, and each time I turn it on. I am using Windows 10 and my HDD is a Seagate Barracuda.

**Is it possible to prevent my internal HDD from spinning up when I wake my computer from sleep?**

Comment: So many disks will die before Microsoft addresses this problem. I think we should sue them for the lost money :)

Answer (score 0):

I have looked, and I don't find a way to do this, even using PowerShell, which is quite disappointing.

I have often wondered whether my extra drives (I have 5 internals I don't need most of the time) power down automatically when I am not using them, but from my searches I can see they don't. Maybe they spin down, but they definitely don't enter a no-power usage scenario, which would be ideal?

Somehow, I feel this is a huge failing by the powers-that-be, especially when we're all trying to go green. Who cares if you have to wait a few seconds while your secondary drive/s boot - there's a reason you disabled them in the first place, not so?

Maybe, I am just a pleb & some Messiah will come save us, let's hope so?

Answer (score 0):

There are some utilities that take care of low-level stuff in Windows like HD Tune Pro - you can try with those. That's the closest solution I know.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure when you wake your computer everything turns on for a corruption, virus and other stuff checks. That's why when you turn on your laptop/pc It may show if there is corruption that you need to fix the disk.

You might have to change it in the actual Bios of the computer as i have learnt that Mac, Windows, and even Linux systems all turn on all storage devices so they get access to data. It is like an inbuilt feature of them.